# Embeded PDF not displaying in WebView Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Web-view in Xamarin.Android. I am loading a website in that and this website has an embedded iframe which hosts a PDF Viewer. The entire website looks fine but this embedded iframe is blank.
If I open same url in Chrome app, it displays a good placeholder for opening that pdf as shown in attach picture. Please help.

```
WebView webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);
webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
webView.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
webView.Settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
webView.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
webView.Settings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
webView.Settings.AllowContentAccess = true;
webView.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(true);
webView.Settings.PluginsEnabled = true;
webView.Settings.SetPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.On);
webView.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;

webView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

webView.LoadUrl(url);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A WebView cannot display a .pdf document.

Embeded or not: no difference.

Comment: I understand that but is there anyway I can show this Placeholder any how just like the chrome app does? I have attached screenshot from chrome app too.

Comment: @Sudhanshu Unfortunately, for Xamarin it can't do it.